# How can I store a whole word in to a single array slot?

Tags: c++

I wanted to ask how can I store a whole word in to a single array slot?

What I want to do is to somehow make this or something similar to this work so that i could access a whole word just in one slot of an array:

```
string words;
words[0] = "First";
words[1] = "Second";
```

Comment: Your `words` is a `string`, i.e. array of `char`s. You need to make `words` an array of `string`s

Comment: Are you asking how to cram "big thing" into "small space"?

Comment: I already got what I needed, thanks! Sometimes people overlook the most simple and obvious mistakes ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `words` to be an array then make it an array

```
string words[2];
words[0] = "First";
words[1] = "Second";
```

Comment: I would honestly say to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) at this point.